# How to loop through an array to check each value to see if specific values are present in batch

Tags: arrays, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a script that finds a user's group memberships and then checks each group to see if specific ones are present. For simplicity's sake, I've made a test script using letters of the alphabet instead. I set an array called Alphabet that has letters A-G as values:

`SET Alphabet=A,B,C,D,E,F,G`

I then set another variable called Letters which are the values I want to search the Alphabet array for to see if they are present (I added 2 numbers as test values to confirm they won't be found in the loop):

`SET Letters=A,4,D,8`

Here is what I have so far (using string substitution in a loop to look for values):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET Alphabet=A,B,C,D,E,F,G
SET Letters=A,4,D,8

SET n=1
SET "MyLetter[!n!]=%Letters:,=" & SET /A n+=1 & SET "MyLetter[!n!]=%"
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,!n!) DO (
    IF "x!Alphabet:MyLetter[%%i]=!"=="x!Alphabet!" (ECHO !MyLetter[%%i]! is present) ELSE (ECHO !MyLetter[%%i]! is NOT present)
    )
ENDLOCAL
```

I want the script to output the following:

```
A is present
4 is NOT present
D is present
8 is NOT present
```

When you run the script, this is the output instead:

```
A is present
4 is present
D is present
8 is present
```

For some reason it is detecting the Letters array values of 4 and 8 are present in the Alphabet array. I believe it might be an issue with my loop but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm hoping it's not a limitation of batch (but if it is, I guess I might have to resort to calling Powershell) but was hoping to try and stick to exclusively batch if possible. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
FOR %%i in (%letters%) DO (
    IF "x!Alphabet:%%i=!"=="x!Alphabet!" (ECHO %%i is NOT present) ELSE (ECHO %%i is present)
    )
```

The reason is that in

```
IF "x!Alphabet:MyLetter[%%i]=!"=="x!Alphabet!" (ECHO !MyLetter[%%i]! is present) ELSE (ECHO !MyLetter[%%i]! is NOT present)
```

You need to substitute the **CONTENTS** of `MyLetter[%%i]`, not the **STRING** `MyLetter[%%i]`

Note also that if the candidate **IS** present in the string, then the substitute method you have used would **alter** the string, so your test is reversed.

Answer (score 2):

If you still wanted to use your existing `For /L` methodology, you can achieve your desired result by including an additional `For` loop:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "Alphabet=A,B,C,D,E,F,G"
Set "Letters=A,4,D,8"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "i=1"
Set "MyLetter[!i!]=%Letters:,=" & Set /A i += 1 & Set "MyLetter[!i!]=%"
For /L %%G In (1,1,!i!) Do For %%H In ("!MyLetter[%%G]!") Do If /I "!Alphabet:%%~H=!" == "!Alphabet!" (Echo %%~H is NOT present) Else Echo %%~H is present

EndLocal
Pause

EndLocal
```

*Note: I included the case insensitive option with the `If` command, feel free to remove `/I` if that is unwanted behavior.*